# Read from web service

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have this web service

http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/currencies

How can I open it and view its data inside `void page_load` function on visual studio 2010?

Sorry i'm beginner with ASP.net.

Comment: @elolos that edit was inappropriate, there is nothing webforms-specific in this question. The place where this code is required (Page_Load) does not change the answers, so no reason to add that tag. Also try to improve more than just adding a single tag, like spelling.

Comment: @CodeCaster It surely is relevant as page load events are specific to webforms and not for example mvc. This makes easier to find this question under a more specific tag than just asp.net.

Also, I would definitely change a couple of spelling errors along with the tag, however this is not possible because of the 6 character limit.

Comment: @elolos read the second sentence of my comment again. And if you can't find enough to fix on a post, the edit probably was too minor anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't really a web service, it seems to be newline-separated values in a text file served over HTTP.

Just use an HttpClient to download the data and split the result on newline.

Comment: i cant do it correctly , can you please add httpclient code that gets the data please :)

Comment: Try [`HttpClient.GetStringAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: you are right its not really web service
i used HttpWebRequest  HttpWebResponse to get data 
and httpclient works for 4.5 framework only

Answer (score 2):

In Page Load Event

```
            if(!IsPostBack)
            { 

            System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

            string data = client.DownloadString("http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/currencies");


            List<string> data1 = data.Split('\n').ToList();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = data1;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
```

Dropdown Index change event

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
            string selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string selectedText = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```

Add AutoPostBack event in dropdown control properties

Thanks
Jai

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) method

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
  {    
       var list = client.DownloadString("http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/currencies");    
       var values= list.Split(Convert.ToChar("\n"));
  }
```